# How to reload unity instance

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I have kept androidKeepPlayerMounted this false , so first time unity loads but when i navigate to any other screen and come back again to unity screen then unity does not load below is the code. Thank you for taking a look.

```
import {
ImageBackground,
StatusBar,
Image,
TouchableOpacity,
View,
TextInput,
SafeAreaView,
Button,
} from 'react-native';
import React, {useRef, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Images from '../../../Styles/Images';
import styles from './Styles';
import UnityView from '@azesmway/react-native-unity';
import {useNavigation, useFocusEffect} from '@react-navigation/native';
import Styles from '../../Auth/Login/Styles';
import {Colors} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
export default function FaceInteraction(props): React.JSX.Element {
const {navigation} = props;
const unityRef = useRef(null);
const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
const [showTextField, setShowTextField] = useState(false);
console.log(unityRef);
const handleInputChange = inputValue => {
setMessage(inputValue);
};

const submitHandler = () => {
const unityData = {
name: message,
age: 3,
};
let jsonedData = JSON.stringify(unityData);
console.log(unityData)
SendData(jsonedData);
};
const delay = (ms: number) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
async function SendData(data: any) {
await delay(500);
console.log('data is sended from react native');
unityRef.current?.postMessage('ReactToUnity', 'GetDatas', data);
}

useEffect(() => {
return () => {
unityRef.current?.componentWillUnmount();
};
}, []);

return (

<View style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
<UnityView
ref={unityRef}
style={{ height: 100%', width: '100%'}}
androidKeepPlayerMounted={false}
onUnityMessage={result => {
console.log('Message Here : ', result.nativeEvent.message);
let d = result.nativeEvent.message;
if (d.includes('home')) {
navigation.navigate('BottomNavigation', {screen: 'HomeTab'});
}
}}
/>

);
}
```

i want when ever i come to unity component it should load.